# Meaning of falsification in different context

Tags: reason, falsifiability, abduction

What is the meaning of devil's advocate. Is it same as falsification/falsifiability ?

Can we use falsifiability/falsification for abductive reasoning ?

Comment: "falsification" in reasoning means: to prove/show that some statement is wrong.

Comment: [Falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) is related to the evaluation process of scientific theories and hypotheses, according to Karl Popper. A theory or hypothesis is falsifiable (or refutable) if it can be logically contradicted by an empirical test.

Comment: [Devil's advocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate), originally a former official position within the Catholic Church, "in common language describes a situation where someone, given a certain point of view, takes a position they do not necessarily agree with, for the sake of debate or to explore the thought further using valid reasoning that both disagrees with the subject at hand and proves their own point valid. "

Comment: Conclusion: they are broadly related.